# Create function to use in creating view for serial number generation base on group by

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have to generate row numbers for my view which will be reset after a group. Following SQL statement works for me.

```
SELECT st_id, class, percentage,
   (CASE section 
        WHEN @cur_sect
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
        ELSE @curRow := 0 END) + 1 AS position,
    @cur_sect := section AS Section
FROM SUM_MARKS,
     (SELECT @curRow := 0, @cur_sect := '') counter
      ORDER BY class, section;
```

When tried to save it using phpmyadmin, warning appear that it contained  variables. So need to write a function or procedure which can be used with other columns. Like **row_number()** built-in function in sql-server.

Comment: You cannot return a result set from a function perhaps you should be looking at triggers.And mysql does have row_number (version 8 or above).

Answer (score 0):

I tried following statement in mysql 8.0.16, it showed the result as expected. 
Create view View1 as SELECT st_id, class, percentage, section, 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY class, section ORDER BY percentage DESC) AS position 
FROM table1 ORDER BY class, section, position;
The solution for those who have mysql 5.7 or less is to use statements with variables, save it in a query builder in Front End like MS Access or Libreoffice Base (direct sql mode), then use in creating form or report. If you need this 'view' to show in a table in web design you can use PHP or equivalent and write this sql statement (with variables) there.